# Updated posts are not sending through feedburner

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am using *Feedburner* for email subscription on my blog when I am posting new post then only *Feedburner* sending to *email subscribers*, if I am updating post is not sending to *subscribers*.

> **Example:** In my blog am posting job updates daily updating pages day by
>   day so it is not sending to subscribers.

https://java-questions-and-answers.blogspot.in/2016/05/it-and-non-it-jobs.html

In this page am posting *new job links*, but *feedburner* is not sending to *subscribers*. So how can I overcome this problem can anyone help me?